# Signing apks with multiple certificates

Tags: android, security, manifest, apk, signing

I am signing my testActivty.apk with certificate C1 and C2 and my serviceActivty with certicate C1 and I put the android:protectionLevel="signature" in service. I see that My activty is no longer able to bind to the service as it gets a SecurityException. This does not happen however if I just try to sign both with certificates C1. Is there any restriction in signing apks with multiple certificates.

I didn't think signing an apk with multiple cert was an issue as when i did a jarsigner verify it was just checking if there was at least 1 certificate signed.

Could some one point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your serviceAcivity only has C1, and thus won't work with an apk which has C1+C2.  Can you try signing serviceActivity with C1+C2?

Comment: Yes it works. But that's not my requirement. I would like my activity to be signed with some other Certificates cause its using another service signed with another certificate.